# References to author or authors in PhD thesis or published paper

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, authorship

In a chapter of my finished PhD thesis I have written "...to the best of the author's knowledge..." several times as a reference to me. Now my supervisor and I would like to publish this chapter in a journal with him and me as (co-)authors (me as first author). Consequently, the phrase in the publication would have to change to "...to the best of the authors' knowledge...".

Could this result in any problems afterwards for the authorship of my PhD thesis?
Could I be accused of making a false statement because I only named myself as the author of this chapter in my PhD thesis?

Or would it be the reasoning that I am the author of my PhD thesis and since this chapter was not published at the time of completion, I did not have to refer to my supervisor as co-author? At least, I have never seen that a supervisor was addressed as a co-author of a chapter in a PhD thesis (unless the chapter was published before the PhD thesis).

Answer (score 5):

You are overthinking this. No one will notice that the apostrophe moved over the 's'. And if they did they would draw no conclusions.

Congratulations on the thesis and the paper.